# End stream from another function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the geolocation package to update the location in the background.

```
Geolocation.locationUpdates(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
    displacementFilter: 10.0, // in meters
    inBackground: true, // by default, location updates will pause when app is inactive (in background). Set to `true` to continue updates in background.
  )
  .listen((result) {
    if(result.isSuccessful) {
      print('UPDATING LOCATION');
      currentPosition['lat'] = result.location.latitude;
      currentPosition['long'] = result.location.longitude;
    }
  });
```

The above code is run when a user starts a 'trip'. When a user wants to end it, another function **endTrips()** is called. How do I stop the locationUpdates from the endTrips() function? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a `StreamSubscription<String> _locationSub;` in your class and set the value in your **startTrips()** 
`_locationSub = Geolocation.locationUpdates(..).listen()`
And if you call **endTrips()** you close the Stream with
`_locationSub?.cancel`